# How can I get aserve installed on my mac and load it within lispbox-0.7?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, practical-common-lisp, lisp-in-a-box

I am on Chapter 26 of "Practical Common Lisp" (excellent book).  I am trying to get to this, downloaded from https://github.com/Apress/practical-common-lisp:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :com.gigamonkeys.web
       (:use :cl :net.aserve :com.gigamonkeys.html))
```

which gives this error:

```
(There is no package named "NET.ASERVE" .
   [Condition of type CCL::NO-SUCH-PACKAGE])
```

After cloning https://github.com/franzinc/aserve.git
I ran:

```
CL-USER> (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :aserve)
```

but got error:

```
There is no package named "EXCL" .
   [Condition of type CCL::NO-SUCH-PACKAGE]
```

I could not find package EXCL so I installed portableaserve and ran:

```
CL-USER> (load "~/GitHub/portableaserve/INSTALL.lisp")
```

but again got:

```
there is no package named "EXCL" .
   [Condition of type CCL::NO-SUCH-PACKAGE]
```

Would someone know how to install allegroserve, including EXCL, within lispbox-0.7 on a mac to run the above defpackage command?

Answer (score 6):

Lisp-in-a-box, while featuring prominently in Practical Common Lisp, is not maintained anymore for quite some years now (the book is from 2005).

I'd recommend using [Portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) as a complete preconfigured environment.

This comes with Quicklisp, so you can just `(ql:quickload "aserve")` then.